# Show an improper integral is infinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $p(x)$ is a polynomial. Define $$g(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}p(x)dx$$ Show that $g(s)$ is infinitely differentiable for $s>0$

I try to compute $g^{\prime}(s)$ using definition,I end up getting $$g^{\prime}(s)=\lim_{y\rightarrow s}\frac{g(y)-g(s)}{y-s}=\lim_{y \rightarrow s}\frac{\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{t}e^{-yx}p(x)dx -\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^{t}e^{-sx}p(x)dx }{y-s} $$
which  looks quite complicated and I don't know how to proceed from here.

Question: Can we interchange derivative and improper integral, i.e. $\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^{\infty}dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d}{ds}dx$?

Can anyone give hints?

Comment: Yes, we can interchange. How to justify it depends. Are you using the Lebesgue or the Riemann integral?

Comment: @DanielFischer:Riemann Integral

Comment: @Idonknow $$g(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}p(x)dx=s^n\int_0^{\infty}\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^n\dfrac{p(x)x^n}{n!}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$g(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}p(x)dx=s^n\int_0^{\infty}\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^n\dfrac{p(x)x^n}{n!}dx\text{ for finite }e^{-sx},p(x)\forall x\in(-\infty,+\infty).$$
The integral $\int_0^{\infty}\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{p(x)x^n}{n!}dx$ evaluates to just a constant $C$, since $p(x)$ is just a polynomial. Is $g(s)=Cs^n$ infinitely differentiable?

Comment: how we justify the existence of limit for both summation and integral?

Comment: @Idonknow See my edit.

Comment: That's wrong. You have $$e^{-sx}p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}s^nx^np(x),$$ but the terms of the sum aren't integrable (unless $p \equiv 0$).